# ANDROID: How to receive broadcast of specific application's notifications?

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am creating an application which perform specific task on receiving broadcast notification from specific application like whats app, viber etc .I have searched about this but did not get any solution. is there any possibility exist to do this action? if exist then please guide me how? :)

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: i did not create code for this action yet . Actually i did not get any idea or query how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Simple Only follow this code and read the documentation from this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

### Manifest File

```
    <receiver android:name=".callbroadcastreceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

### In Java callbroadcastreceiver file

public class callbroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String state = intent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        //Phone is ringing
    }
    else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        //Call received
        Toast.makeText( context,"call received",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        context.startService( new Intent( context,BoundService.class ) );
    }
    else if (state.equals( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        //Call Dropped or rejected
        context.stopService(  new Intent( context,BoundService.class ) );
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can check on the status bar notification but you can't read them. If it can be it really danger situation for vulnerabilty.

But using [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html#create), you can only listen to all notification on the notification bar.

Comment: i do not wanna read , just perform task on getting notification from specific app

Comment: Ok then you can read above the link. You can add the package name to the list and follow the notification.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) for this. Users may not be interested in giving your app the rights to monitor their notifications, though, which is why the user must manually enable this for your app.

but you can not read the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to access your Notification form any Application

```
    import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
    import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
    import com.qna.vbage.Pref;
    import static com.qna.vbage.FieldVerification.setRingerMode;


    public class NotificationService extends AccessibilityService {


        protected void onServiceConnected() {
            AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
            info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
            info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
            info.notificationTimeout = 3000;
            setServiceInfo(info);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "onAccessibilityEvent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("VBage", "FML");
            if (e.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
               // Toast.makeText(this, "onAccessibilityEvent 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("VBage", "Recieved event");
                Parcelable data = e.getParcelableData();
                if (data instanceof Notification) {
                   // Toast.makeText(this, "onAccessibilityEvent 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("VBage", "Recieved notification");
                    Notification notification = (Notification) data;
                    Log.d("VBage", "ticker: " + notification.tickerText);
                    Log.d("VBage", "icon: " + notification.icon);
                    Log.d("VBage", "notification: " + e.getText());     
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInterrupt() {
            setRingerMode(NotificationService_API18.this, AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        }
    }
```

Set Permission in your Manifest

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

set Service in Manifest to Call when App Start

```
   <service android:name=".NotificationService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
        </service>
```

Create **xml** in you Values folder *res/Values/xml/accessibilityservice.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100" />
```

You have to Enable Accessibility Manually for your App put below code in your Activity where you want to start Using this Service

```
if (!isAccessibilitySettingsOn(getApplicationContext())) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Go!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                   startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS));
                }
            });
            showCusDialog(dialog, "Warning!", R.drawable.ic_warning, getString(R.string.accessiblityString));

        }
```

to Start Service from Activity

```
startService(new Intent(mActivity, NotificationService_API18.class));
```